# Waiting for an element to load using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've had a good look through here but the web element waits don't seem to fit into my code.

I'm fairly new to Java and Selenium. I want to try and get a wait for element into my code before it times out.

Any suggestions?

It's crashing when it hits this point because the page does take a while to search for this address.

```
@Step ("Verifying landmark")
public void validatingLandmark(String s){
    String actualValue = getDriver().findElement(By.id("MainContent_lblLandmarkUPRN")).getText();
    assertEquals(s, actualValue);
    TimeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html). For instance, explicitly wait for an element to become visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), timeOut);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("MainContent_lblLandmarkUPRN")));

String actualValue = element.getText();
```

You can also use `textToBePresentInElement` Expected Condition:

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.id("MainContent_lblLandmarkUPRN"), s));
```

Comment: Yes, Explicit wait is better than Implicit wait. It is recommended to use explicit wait.

Comment: Hi just tried this out the timeOut I've had to change to TimeOut to match my method. I ran the code again and this time it's given me this error:- 

Timed out after 0 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: MainContent_lblLandmarkUPRN Build info: version:

Have I done something wrong? Maybe becuase I changed the timeOut?

Comment: @afcbpete what timeout value are you setting? Set it to, e.g. 10 seconds. It would mean selenium would wait **up to 10 seconds** checking the visibility every 500 ms (by default).

Comment: Sorted it now. Works a dream. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Explicit wait or Fluent Wait

**Example of Explicit Wait -**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence,20);
WebElement aboutMe;
aboutMe= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("about_me")));
```

**Example of Fluent Wait -**

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)                            
.withTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)          
.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)          
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);    

  WebElement aboutMe= wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {       
public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) { 
return driver.findElement(By.id("about_me"));     
 }  
});
```

Check this [TUTORIAL](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/10/implicit-wait-explicit-wait-and-fluent.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use implicit wait or sleep here

**Implicit wait:**
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

**Sleep**
`Thread.sleep(2000L);` in this case use throws InterruptedException

Hope it will help