# .click() is not consistent in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a website that has a carousel with 3 buttons for 3 carousel items. html code for this is as follows;

```
<ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;">
<li class="slick-active" aria-hidden="false">
<button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">1</button>
</li>
<li aria-hidden="true">
<button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">2</button>
</li>
<li aria-hidden="true">
<button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">3</button>
</li>
</ul>
```

when the site is loaded, the 1st button is enabled. 
Clicking on the 2nd button in the carousel changes the html as follows;

```
<ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;">
<li class="" aria-hidden="true">
<button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">1</button>
</li>
<li class="slick-active" aria-hidden="false">
<button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0" 
style="">2</button>
</li>
<li aria-hidden="true">
<button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">3</button>
</li>
</ul>
```

I need to click on each carousel button and capture the respective header heading. following is what I did so far. However, this doesn't work consistently. But, if I debug the code, then all 3 headings are captured correctly.

```
    int CarouselItem=2;
    for (int i = 1; i<=CarouselItems.size(); i++) {

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //*getting the page header heading
           WebElement PageHeaderHeading = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/main/section/div/div/div/div[" + i + "]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/h1"));
            System.out.println("Page header text of "+i+" now is " + PageHeaderHeading.getText());

         //* clicking on the 2nd and 3rd carousel buttons   
        if(CarouselItem<=CarouselItems.size())
        {
            WebElement CarouselButtonToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[(@aria-hidden='true') and button[contains(text(),'"+CarouselItem+"')]]"));
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            CarouselButtonToClick.click();
            CarouselItem = CarouselItem + 1;
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help me out? What is wrong in this code for it to not give the headings of all 3 carousel items consistently?

Comment: Sounds like you need to explicitly wait for the page to load based on "*when debugging, it works*". Check out [Waiting for an element to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503518/waiting-for-an-element-to-load-using-selenium).

Comment: @VinceEmigh, thanks a lot! explicit wait worked well for me :)